# If a sequence approaches infinity, then all its subsequences approach infinity

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to do this proof, that if $x_n\to\infty$ then all its subsequences $x_{n_k}\to\infty$ as well.

I understand that there always exists a subsequence of a sequence that approaches infinity that approaches infinity, as you can just remove the first few values and arrive at the subsequence, but how do I prove all subsequences approach infinity?

Comment: The question in your title differs from that in the question.

Comment: A divergent series must not go to infinity. What is with $(-1)^n$? This sequence diverges but there are subsequences, which are convergent

Comment: Do you mean properly divergent? To +\infty or -\infty?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I will correct the question. Also, I mean +infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in your title is mistaken: a divergent sequence may have
convergent subsequences.

To the question in the main text.
As always one needs to recall the definition of diverging to infinity:
$x_n\to\infty$ if for all $M$, then $x_n\le M$ for only finitely
many $n$. This entails that $x_{n_k}\le M$ for only finitely many $k$,
so that $x_{n_k}\to\infty$

Comment: Simple, and makes perfect sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $M\in \mathbb{N}$ then by definition we have that there is a $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > n_{0}$ then

$$|x_{n}| > M$$

Now pick a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ and let $n_{k} > n_0$ . Therefore:

$$|x_{n_{k}}| > M$$

Since $M$ is arbitrary we have that:

$$\lim_{n_{k} \rightarrow \infty } x_{n_{k}}=\infty$$